# Is it actually necessary to forward CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage to an MFC DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mfc

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/regular-dlls-dynamically-linked-to-mfc?view=vs-2019) says:

> Note that the CWinApp::Run mechanism does not apply to a DLL, because
>   the application owns the main message pump. If your DLL brings up
>   modeless dialogs or has a main frame window of its own, your
>   application's main message pump must call a DLL-exported routine that
>   calls CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage.

However when I run an experiment to verify this, the modeless dialog appears to work fine, regardless of whether I do or don't follow the quoted advice.

I modified "DLLScreenCap" sample application (linked in that same article) to have a modeless dialog which is opened by DLL code.  Because the sample executable code forwards PreTranslateMessage to the DLL, hitting a breakpoint in a button handler in the modeless dialog shows a call stack like this:

- OnBnClickedButton1 handler in my DLL
- (external code)
- AfxWndProcDllStatic in "dllmodul.cpp" (an MFC file)
- (external code)
- FilterDllMsg (function exported by my DLL to forward PreTranslateMessage)
- PreTranslateMessage (message handler in my EXE calling into my DLL)
- (external code)
- WinMain in the executable

However if I comment out the code in executable which was forwarding PreTranslate message to the DLL, I still get functionality in the modeless dialog.  Now the button handler call stack is shorter:

- OnBnClickedButton1 handler in my DLL
- (external code)
- AfxWndProcDllStatic in "dllmodul.cpp" (an MFC file)
- (external code)
- WinMain in the executable

In other words, it appears to me that if I don't forward the messages manually in PreTranslateMessage, Windows and/or the MFC framework still ensures the message gets to the DLL.

It seems the only difference is that the PreTranslateMessage virtual function in the CWinApp doesn't get called.  If the DLL doesn't use this handler, is there any other need or reason to forward PreTranslateMessage?  Is it bad not to?

P.S.  The same question applies to forwarding the OnIdle event.

Comment: The `OnBnClickedButton1` arrived because the `WM_COMMAND` message was delivered to the button *after* translation. Your code is not running during the PreTranslate phase. The DLL never actually received the `PreTranslateMessage`. If your DLL uses `PreTranslateMessage` to do something interesting (e.g,. custom dialog box navigation), then that interesting thing won't happen.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess the real question is, if user code isn't doing something interesting, will not running it break anything in the MFC framework.

Comment: Also, while I have your attention, how is it that the button handler doesn't require AFX_MANAGE_STATE in the DLL, whereas the PreTranslateMessage forwarding code does?

Comment: [TN058: MFC Module State Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn058-mfc-module-state-implementation): *"AFX_MODULE_STATE does not need to be put in every function in the DLL. For example, `InitInstance` can be called by the MFC code in the application without AFX_MODULE_STATE [...]. **The same is true for all message map handlers**. Regular MFC DLLs actually have a special master window procedure that automatically switches the module state before routing any message."*